# How to download Youtube video's views data on daily or weekly basis. For example, views of a video on day - 1, day -2 .. day -10 etc

Tags: video, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

For my application, I require to create a data set of youtube video meta data including views on daily basis. For example, views that a particular video received on day-1, day-2 ... day-10. I checked out Youtube apis and I could download the data of a video; however, I could find any api that gives views details per day.
I checked out all operations of api -> https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search

Please let me know how can I download historical data of Youtube including above specified requirement?

Answer (score 1):

You won't get an API for that. But you can find the stats of the YouTube video's Views by following ways:

1. Go to the video
2. Click on the more button (next to share)
3. Click statistics
4. Now you have all the graphs that youtube offers for videos you dont own!

Hope i helped :)

Comment: The OP is looking for an API call that will provide the data, not a process that involves using their UI.

Answer (score 0):

YouTube API doesn't have viewCounts by day, just the total, so you would have to request the same videos every day and store the difference in the daily viewCount yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add that you're current link is looking at the API for video playback.

You want to check the [**Youtube Analytics**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/) API. What you seek would be classed under [**Metrics**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/dimsmets/mets).

There is only option of checking of total views, so you'll have to note the daily views yourself as suggested by @**johnh10** (perhaps via an automatic daily script?).

Comment: Yes, I thought of that option and I am working on that for new videos. But I also want historical data (~6 months - 1 year). Is there any way to get historical data? I tried search api, which gives historical data of channel (7 day, 1 month, 180 days etc..), but access is limited to owner only (channelId==<your_channel>). For other channel, access is forbidden.

Comment: Did you found any other option for this? @NikhilBhide